# Why Chromium does not open the Gmail? (reporting a certificate error)

Tags: gmail, certificate, chromium, https, ssl-certificate

The error I get:

---

### The server's security certificate is revoked!

You attempted to reach **www.google.com**, but the certificate that the server presented has been revoked by its issuer. This means that the security credentials the server presented absolutely should not be trusted. You may be communicating with an attacker. You should not proceed.

---

It works fine in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue that deals with having the incorrect system time set.  Verify your system time against a network time server first then see if the issue reoccurs.

Here's the info on the bug:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=22796

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile I worked it around by turning the certificate check off.

Comment: Synching the system time worked for me